# iOS - Mapbox with clustering, MGLSymbolStyleLayer not showing custom images

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I am using this [ios-sdk-examples > ClusteringExample](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/master/Examples/Swift/ClusteringExample.swift) to cluster markers, in addition to this example, I need to show different UIImages for each marker (means each marker have its own UIImage), I have tried following:

```
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts", features: self.features, options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: 22])
style.addSource(source)

// remoteImages is an array of tuple [(image: UIImage, key: String)]
remoteImages.forEach { item in
    mapView.style!.setImage(item.image, forName: item.key)
    let layer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: item.key, source: source)
    layer.iconImageName = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: item.key as NSString)
    layer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K != YES", "cluster")
    style.addLayer(layer)
}
```

But above code shows one single UIImage for all unclustered markers (screenshot attached), any idea where I need to specify these custom images?

**Update-1:** self.features is an array `[MGLPointFeature]`, each `MGLPointFeature` has nothing more than following:

```
let feature = MGLPointFeature()
feature.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: LatValue, longitude: LngValue)
feature.attributes = ["id": IntegerValue]
```

[image]

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: @R-Aamir, are u able to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want to show clusterd markers,  you'll have to write

`%K == YES` not `%K != YES`.

```
 layer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == YES", "cluster")
```

Comment: it does not work, %K == YES is used for clustered layers, original example https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/